# Mouse element movement within a react div

Tags: reactjs

Let's say i have

```html
<div>
<p> Some text </p>
</div>
```

I also have a hidden component with animation - an icon and when you hover over this div div the component appears and should move behind the cursor. I implemented the appearance of the component on hooks and using the onMouseLeave and onMouseEnter methods, but it is static, it appears in a certain place. I can’t figure out how to bind a component to a cursor. I think towards onMouseMove, maybe hooks are not needed in this case either.

Comment: How are you animating it? Check out react-spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want that a specific component will be displayed where ever cursor is,

```
const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState({ top: 0, left: 0 })
const onMouseMove = e =>
    setCursorPosition({ top: e.screenY, left: e.screenX });
  
    return <div onMouseMove={onMouseMove} >
             <div style={{position: 'absolute', ...cursorPosition }} />
           </div>
```